# Add url parameter via jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that on submit I want to pass the email address value to the url as a parameter. How can I incorporate that into my current setup below:

```
<form action="/event/" method="POST" id="signupForm">
```

And here's my

```
$("#signupForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var email = $("#EmailAddress").val();

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: form.attr('action'),
           data: form.serialize(),
           success: function(data)
           {
               console.log(data); //data contain response from your php script
               register_signup();
               form.replaceWith("<br /><p>Thanks for signing up!</p>");
           }
         });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just append it to the url:

```
$("#signupForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var email = $("#EmailAddress").val();

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: form.attr('action') + '?email=' + email,
           data: form.serialize(),
           success: function(data)
           {
               console.log(data); //data contain response from your php script
               register_signup();
               form.replaceWith("<br /><p>Thanks for signing up!</p>");
           }
         });
});
```

In the server you will need to retrieve the data from the query string for the parameters in the URL and from POST for the data posted from your form:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query);
echo $query['email'];
```

And for post values just simply use `$_POST['input_name']`.

Comment: Great thanks, wasn't sure on the syntax. If I understand it correctly, as it's ajax the page won't reload so the parameter doesn't show in the url, is that right? I'm trying to call a php file that then pulls in the parameter but it doesn't appear to pull it in.

Comment: See the edit, hope it helps. You might as well include the email in the form as a post value instead of adding it to the URL, no? If you don't want the users to see it just add it as a hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can add an input field with hidden flag to your form and set its value to the email address before serializing.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `url: form.attr('action')` use it like

```
url: "/event/?email="+email
```

OR

```
url: form.attr('action') + '?email=' + email
```

So,the ajax will be like

```
$("#signupForm").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  var email = $("#EmailAddress").val();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
   url:  "/event/?email="+email, //OR  url: form.attr('action') + '?email=' + email,
   data: form.serialize(),
   success: function(data){}
 });

});
```